# Linux VPS Terminal Management

Tags: linux, vps, terminal, manage

I deployed a small Linux VPS to host a few personal websites and applications.

However, due to security and performance concerns, I do not want to install any server management panels.

How can I handle basic operations such as managing mysql db, adding a domain name, setting up e-mail accounts, etc. in the most practical way via the terminal?

I searched for "Terminal Server Manager" but I couldn't find much. Scripts that allow me to manage each service separately can also be useful. In summary, I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Write command via command line

Comment: @RomeoNinov Of course! How did I not think of this!

Comment: `managing mysql db, adding a domain name, setting up e-mail accounts, etc.` reminds me of the Monty Python where the guy says "today on How To Do It we will learn to play the flute, build box girder bridges, and irrigate the Sahara and make it cultivatable. But first here's Ben to talk about setting up mailboxes."

Comment: The question was quite simple; I need scripting tools on terminal to manage a linux server like cpanel, webmin etc.